# Does the different syntax for NPM imply anything particular about Angular packages?

Tags: node.js, git, angular, npm

Usually, when I install a package using NPM, I apply the syntax as follows.

> npm install some-package-name --save

However, I noticed that when I visit [sites for NPMing Angular 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core), the syntax is different. The packages main name is preceded by *at*, "@", and the constituting parts are installed individually using *slash*, "/".

> npm install @angular/core --save
>   npm install @angular/compiler --save

I'm surprised that the subpackages aren't added as dependencies like I'm used to see with the other packages (alternatively as separate packages as it's common with other frameworks). Does it tell something significant about it?

I'm also confused by the usage of *at* and *slash*. I googlearched for those in connection with NPM and Git but it's difficult to find anything useful as Google seems to disregard certain search words.

Does it have anything to do with the not-included packages of *rxjs* and *zone.js*? Very confused about the implication of those. All the guides use them **but** they're not a part of Angular 2 distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new naming convention exists to make it clear that this is an Angular 2 component rather than Angular 1. If you are asking about other syntactic differences consult this cheat sheet as a starting point:

`https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/a1-a2-quick-reference.html`